# How to install Postfix 3.7.4 or newer (ex: 3.8.3) on AlmaLinux, Rocky, CentOS and other RedHat 9.2 derivatives

Tags: software-installation, postfix, openssl, alma-linux

I'm on AlmaLinux 9.2 (Turquoise Kodkod) with the most recent Postfix version available being 3.5.9, and I’m facing an issue with Postfix and OpenSSL 3 ([link](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/18866)) which was fixed on Postfix 3.7.4.

I saw that newer versions may be available on development channel ([link](https://rpms.remirepo.net/rpmphp/zoom.php?rpm=postfix)), currently 3.8.3, but I don't know how to enable it, as well as how to only use it for Postfix.